# How to host an MFC/Win32 "Print Setup" dialog in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to host an MFC/Win32  "Print Setup" dialog in a WPF application ?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. If you have any findings please share

Comment: I would like to get a Print Setup dialog box in my wpf application. In win32 applications, there is a provision to display a Print Setup dialog box by setting the PD_PRINTSETUP flag in a call to the PrintDlg function. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/print-dialog-box#print-setup-dialog-box)

Comment: The following link helped. link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/336f985a-58a0-4400-bd91-8d49e761080e/print-setup-dialog?forum=winforms Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

Creating a PrintDialog control at run-time is simple. The first step is to create an instance of PrintDialog class and then call the ShowDialog method. The following code snippet creates a PrintDialog control.

```
PrintDialog PrintDialog1 = newPrintDialog();  
PrintDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

PrintDocument object represents a document to be printed. Once a PrintDocument is created, we can set the Document property of PrintDialog as this document. After that we can also set other properties.The following code snippet creates a PrintDialog and sends some text to a printer.

```
privatevoid PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    PrintDialog printDlg = newPrintDialog();  
    PrintDocument printDoc = newPrintDocument();  
    printDoc.DocumentName = "Print Document";  
    printDlg.Document = printDoc;  
    printDlg.AllowSelection = true;  
    printDlg.AllowSomePages = true;  
    //Call ShowDialog  
    if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) printDoc.Print();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here the printdialog class of WPF is used. The requirement is to show print setup dialog box of win32, or something that looks similar.

Comment: may be this is helpful https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/pagesetupdialog-in-C-Sharp/#:~:text=The%20PageSetupDialog%20class%20represents%20the,including%20margins%20and%20paper%20orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the winforms printdialog by adding a reference to System.Windows.Forms or dllimport the one in comdlg32.dll
An example call can be found here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/comdlg32.PrintDlg